# handle custom message if unable to delete data due to foreign key error in laravel rest api

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, rest

How to create a custom message to distinguish the database error message code because I can't delete the primary key from a table that contains foreign keys with other database errors.

my controller code:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    try {
        $object =  Service::destroy($id);

        if(!$object){
            return $this->error("No service with ID $id", null, 404);
        }

        return $this->success("Service Deleted", $object);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $this->response($e->getMessage(), null, $e->getCode());
    } catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){ 
        return $this->response($ex->getMessage(), null, 500);
    }
}
```

my response code:

```
public function response($message, $data = null, $statusCode = 200)
{
    if(!$message){
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Message is required'], 500);
    }

    if($statusCode >= 200 && $statusCode < 300){
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $message,
            'error' => false,
            'code' => $statusCode,
            'results' => $data,
        ], $statusCode);
    } else {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => $message,
            'error' => true,
            'code' => $statusCode,
        ], $statusCode);
    }
}
```

my relation database:

```
packages : {id, id_service, name_package, price}
services : {id, service_name}
```

result from controller:

```
{
    "message":"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nr_laundry`.`packages`, CONSTRAINT `packages_id_service_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_service`) REFERENCES `services` (`id`)) (SQL: delete from `services` where `id` = 26)",
    "error":true,
    "code":500
}
```

in the my controller code `catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex)` is the message handle for database exception queries, but with an error message of 500, it could be an error message of 500 occurrences with other database errors.

So how can I display messages with unique error codes specific to various errors in the database including this foreignkey error.

examples of the results I want if error foreign key:

```
{
    "message":"service cannot be deleted, because there is a data package (example 1, example, example3 ...) which has the same id_service, namely 26 (name_service)",
    "error":true,
    "code":500
}
```

examples of the results I want if error database connection:

```
{
    "message":"database not connected",
    "error":true,
    "code":500
}
```

and etc.... can it be made like that?, please help me, thanks

Comment: You should put more specific block first. For example `\Illuminate\Database\QueryException` before more generic `Exception`.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the statusCode of the Exception, the code is 23000. You can do:

```php
try {
   ... your code
} 
catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex) {
   if($ex->getCode() === '23000') {
       ...handle your response
   } 
}
```

However I would handle this in the `ExceptionHandler` file inside `App\Exceptions\Handler.php` inside the `render()` doing something like:

```php
if($exception instanceof QueryException) {
   if($exception->getCode() === '23000') {
      return response()->json(['message' => "service cannot be deleted, because there is a data package (example 1, example, example3 ...) which has the same id_service, namely 26 (name_service)"], 500);
   }
}
```

Comment: Almost never code is a string. Better would be loose check with `$ex->getCode() == 23000`.